# postgresql select into

Tags: postgresql, select, plpgsql

I am trying to create postgres script but I am having troubles to return value from max() function insead of table row.

this is important part of script:

```
                DECLARE index SMALLINT;
                SELECT max(bag_index) INTO index FROM booking_bags 
                WHERE bid = NEW.bid AND 
                      pid = NEW.pid AND 
                      fid = NEW.fid AND 
                      ordered_bag_id = NEW.ordered_bad_id;
```

I get this error: invalid type name "max(bag_index) INTO index FROM booking_bags 
                    WHERE bid "
LINE 6:                     SELECT max(bag_index) INTO index FROM bo...

Anyone have an idea how to cast value from max function into declared variable?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the complete function

Answer (score 0):

```
            DECLARE @index SMALLINT;
            SELECT @index = max(bag_index) FROM booking_bags 
            WHERE bid = NEW.bid AND 
                  pid = NEW.pid AND 
                  fid = NEW.fid AND 
                  ordered_bag_id = NEW.ordered_bad_id;
```

Comment: That is invalid for Postgres